# Why is WaitGroup.Wait() hanging when using it with go test?

Tags: go, goroutine, go-testing

Here's a simple example of what I mean

```golang
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestWaitGroup(t *testing.T) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    quitSig := make(chan struct{})
    go func(wg sync.WaitGroup, quitChan, chan struct{}) {
        defer func() {
            t.Log("Done...")
            wg.Done()
            t.Log("Done!")
        }()
        t.Log("waiting for quit channel signal...")
        <-quitChan
        t.Log("signal received")
    }(wg, quitSig)
    time.Sleep(5*time.Second)
    t.Log("Done sleeping")
    close(quitSig)
    t.Log("closed quit signal channel")
    wg.Wait()
    t.Log("goroutine shutdown")
}
```

When I run this, I get the following

```sh
=== RUN   TestWaitGroup
    main.go:18: waiting for quit channel signal...
    main.go:23: Done sleeping
    main.go:25: closed quit signal channel
    main.go:20: signal received
    main.go:14: Done...
    main.go:16: Done!
```

Where it just hangs until it timesout. If you just do `defer wg.Done()` the same behaviour is observed. I'm running `go1.18`. Is this a bug or am I using not using WaitGroups properly in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- don't copy `sync.WaitGroup`: from the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup):

  - `A WaitGroup must not be copied after first use.`
- you need a `wg.Add(1)` before launching your work - to pair with the `wg.Done()`

---

```
wg.Add(1) // <- add this

go func (wg *sync.WaitGroup ...) { // <- pointer
}(&wg, quitSig) // <- pointer to avoid WaitGroup copy
```

https://go.dev/play/p/UmeI3TdGvhg

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a copy of the waitgroup, so the goroutine does not affect the  waitgroup declared in the outer scope. Fix it by:

```
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, quitChan, chan struct{}) {
     ...
    }(&wg, quitSig)
```